# OpenXML: Read a word file , Add some text and open it without saving it in ASP.Net Web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read a template file from disk and add a paragraph to it. Once done, i want to open this as a new file . The template should not have the changes saved into it. I tried the code below and the result is , the template is getting modified with the change but the file that is opening in browser does not have those changes. Clearly I am not getting the modified stream in response. How do I do that and also avoid making change to the template file .

```
public class DocumentCreator
    {
        public static void CreateDoc()
        {
            string strDoc = @"C:\Ash\foo.docx";
            string txt = "Bruno Rovani";

            using (Stream stream = File.Open(strDoc, FileMode.Open))
            {
                OpenAndAddToWordprocessingStream(stream, txt);
            }
        }

        public static void OpenAndAddToWordprocessingStream(Stream stream, string txt)
        {
            // Open a WordProcessingDocument based on a stream.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                // Assign a reference to the existing document body.
                Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                // Add new text.
                Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));

                // HTTP response
                HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.docx");

                //stream = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream();
                stream.Position = 0;
                stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

Added    `wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();`

PS: The template is still being modified. Don't think there is way to avoid this but since I will be doing a find and replace in real scenario it is not a big problem for me.

so the function looks like

```
public static void OpenAndAddToWordprocessingStream(Stream stream, string txt)
        {
            // Open a WordProcessingDocument based on a stream.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                // Assign a reference to the existing document body.
                Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                // Add new text.
                Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
                **wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();**

                // HTTP response
                HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.docx");

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

            }
        }
```